# Loadrunner - Web_reg_save_param_ex - Where the data is saved?

Tags: loadrunner

I am able to successfully use this function and correlate the data within the same scenario. Can somebody guide that how can I use this data in different scenarios.
Can I save the data for future use?

Comment: I am sure James will be able to answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Table Server or pull the data from the database server at the end of test

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple c function to store the correlated values in a .dat/.csv file for future use
char * filename = "c:\LRScripts\logfile.dat";
long file_stream;

```
 FileWrite(char *s)
{
        if ((file_stream = fopen(filename, "a+")) == NULL)  { 
            lr_error_message ("Cannot open or create %s", filename);   
            return -1;
        }

        fprintf(file_stream, "%s\n",s);
        fclose(file_stream);
    return 0;
}
```

At the begining of Action.c

```
char buff[300];
```

Right Before the end of the Action

```
memset (buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
sprintf(buff, "lr_eval_string("{AppNo_C}"),lr_eval_string("{userID}")lr_eval_string("{SSN_1}"),lr_eval_string("{SSN2}"),lr_eval_string("{SSN_3}""));
FileWrite(buff);
```

Comment: Remember, it's not just one user writing to the file, it's all of the users of this type, hence the recommendation for using the virtual table server, which is a part of LoadRunner, or pulling the data from the database server with a query at the end of the test